# Quelle est l'origine du mot « orange » ?

Tags: étymologie, botanique

Ma question est issue d'une petite plaisanterie à laquelle j'aurais voulu avoir une vraie réponse :

> L'orange s'appelle-t-elle comme ça à cause de sa couleur ou est-ce que la couleur orange tire son nom du fruit ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[D'après le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/orange), l'appellation de la couleur orange est arrivée après le fruit, en 1553. On a d'ailleurs commencé par l'appeler "la couleur d'orange".

Le nom du fruit venait de l'arabe *narang* "pomme d'oranger", dont le *n* a été perdu, et le *a* aurait été transformé en *o* à cause de la ville d'Orange.

En revanche, dans certains pays, le nom du fruit et le nom de la couleur n'ont aucun rapport. Dans certains pays du nord de l'Europe par exemple, on s'appuie sur la provenance du fruit, et l'orange n'est donc pas une *pomme d'oranger* mais une *pomme de Chine*. La couleur orange se dit cependant bien *orange*.

Comment: J'ai rarement lu une réponse autant complète, détaillé et compréhensible que la tienne. Merci !

Answer (score 6):

Voir [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/orange).

*Orange* vient de l'arabe *nārang(a)* et du persan *narang* qui ne veut pas dire, pour autant que je le sache, « orange » (la couleur).

Answer (score 4):

En français, la couleur est arrivée après le fruit, mais si l'on remonte aux origines de ce mot, il est possible que le persan *narangi* soit le résultat de la combinaison *anar* ( rouille ) et *rang-i* ( couleur ), « de couleur rouille », et que ce soit donc bien sa couleur qui ait donné son nom au fruit.

Références:

http://iranian.com/GuiveMirfendereski/2005/December/Fruity/
http://iranian.com/GuiveMirfendereski/2005/December/Narangi/index.html