# What was the orange colour called before the fruit became well-known?

Tags: histoire, terminologie

In the accepted answer to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6643/quelle-est-lorigine-du-mot-orange), we find this remark:

> D'après le TLF, l'appellation de la couleur orange est arrivée après le fruit, en 1553. On a d'ailleurs commencé par l'appeler "la couleur d'orange".

What, if anything, was used to refer to the colour we now know as "orange" before this subtropical fruit became well-known in Europe?

Not all colours have their own names in all languages, suggesting that the language support different conceptual schemes of colour (a fact considered interesting for what I consider the generally dubious [Sapir-Whorf hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity)). For example, in Russian, [there are two unrelated words](http://www.pnas.org/content/104/19/7780.full) for two colours that we would translate as variations of one colour: *goluboy* "light blue" and *siniy* "dark blue". Conversely, [some languages don't distinguish between blue and green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%E2%80%93green_distinction_in_language) with separate words.

How was the colour orange conceptualized in European languages (for the purposes of this forum, specifically French)? Did it have its own name? Or was it referred to as "light red" or "dark yellow", or some other term that made reference to an established colour?

Comment: We should look at what it was in Latin and Greek, if it was there, also at other Romance languages.

Comment: True — and then figure out whether *they* used the word first for the fruit or the colour, and if the former what they called the colour. ;) One site gives me *aurantius* in Latin for "having the colour of the fruit of an orange tree", which is a telling wording! [Another](http://ow.ly/JoKI309ZlQw) gives *aureus* and *luteus*, but I believe those are "gold" and a variant of "yellow" respectively...

Comment: Woodhouse gives me [*xanthos*](http://ow.ly/3Vsm309ZlAj) for the Ancient Greek, but Perseus-Tufts has two other roots: [*kirros*](http://ow.ly/qMk7309ZlBQ) "orange-tawny" and [*sandara/kinos*](http://ow.ly/JQMe309ZlDF) "of orange colour". Unfortunately, my Greek is much too poor to recognize these roots.

Comment: Those two made it in French IMHO in specialized words. But again, we face the problem of the exact nuance of the colour.

Comment: I found _aurantius_ too, and its root in Sanskrit. _Aurantius_ sounds so much like _orange_... was it forgotten in the Middle Ages, then reintroduced later, associated with the fruit?

Comment: Very interesting — in fact, Wiktionary [claims](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aurantius) the direct root to Latin is our old friend *naranja* (itself from [Sanskrit](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=orange&allowed_in_frame=0), as you mentioned!). That would certainly move our French problem back in time in the same way. I'm beginning to suspect, between this and your answer, that they referred to a set of similar shades by other terms — thus my question wrongly presupposes that they felt much need to refer directly to the shade orange per se before borrowing the terms for the fruit.

Comment: Yeap, plus "orange" has many shades. Maybe it's just the name of a particular than appeared ni 1553, while the other shades were there all along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'introduction du mot *orange* pour le fruit semble beaucoup plus ancienne d'après TLFi ([même référence](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/orange)). [*Safran*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/safran) se trouve un peu plus tôt; vers le 12e siècle, et *safran* est *jaune orangé* plutôt qu'*orange*.

Le cuivre vient à l'esprit comme une matière dont la couleur peut se rapprocher de l'orange, et le métal est connu depuis l'Antiquité (ce qui ne dit rien sur l'utilisation du mot *cuivre* comme nom de couleur).

*Fauve*, *ocre*, *cinabre* sont des mots liés à des nuances d'orange et il faudrait vérifier leur usage ancien.

Une autre piste serait les noms utilisés pour les couleurs en *héraldique* avant le 16e siècle. Malheureusement, je n'ai trouvé que des références héraldiques "récentes", utilisant déjà le mot *orangé* - en fait, cela est révélateur, comme le montrera la suite (le Moyen-Âge n'aime pas la couleur *orange*).

Pour ce qui est du Latin, que je consulte dans la recherche d'un mot en Vieux Français, je copie d'un autre [forum](http://projetbabel.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14828):

> *... le problème se pose de la délimitation entre le rouge et le jaune: celle-ci n'est pas forcément nette.*
>
> - ***Croceus*** désigne le jaune en renvoyant au safran : dans l'élégie à Mécène (Appendice Virgilien) : il est associé à roseus, purpureus, comme épithète de l'Aurore, ce qui le rapproche de l'orangé.
> - ***Flammeus***: c'est la couleur du feu : orange, certes, mais qui peut tendre aussi sur le jaune.
> - ***Luteus** renvoie à la sarrette, plante utilisée en teinturerie pour donner une sorte de jaune : chez Ovide, Métamorphoses (15. 351), il désigne le soufre jaune pâle, mais chez Lucain (2.361), il est associé à flammeus!*

Il est à noter que les premiers orangers arrivent en Europe seulement au XIVe siècle, bien que les Espagnols connaissent cet arbre par l'intermédiaire des Arabes à partir du XIe siècle.

Un autre [passage](http://www.milleetunefeuilles.fr/blog-1001-feuilles/Orange-symbolisme-histoire-et-expressions-notre-serie-des-couleurs) intéressant, qui indiquerait que "l'orange" tel que nous le connaissons n'existait peut-être pas au Moyen-Age:

> *Au Moyen-Age, les mélanges étant considérés comme impurs (influence du christianisme…), la couleur orange n'était pas obtenue à partir du jaune et du rouge, mais grâce au safran, puis au "bois brésil", une essence provenant des Indes et de Ceylan - qui donna son nom au Brésil. Rappelons-nous qu'à cette époque, les femmes rousses étaient souvent accusées de sorcellerie, au point de finir sur le bûcher…*

Finalement, [ce document](http://www.academia.edu/8583394/L._HABLOT_L_orange_et_le_vert_au_Moyen_Age_Vert_et_Orange_deux_couleurs_%C3%A0_travers_l_histoire_GREVY_J_MANIGAND_C._et_TURREL_D._%C3%A9d._Limoges_2013_p._21-42) semble être la bonne référence. Je n'en reproduis ici que la toute première phrase:

> *Traiter de la couleur orange au Moyen-Âge revient quasiment à évoquer
>   une couleur qui n’existe pas, du moins pas telle que nous l’entendons
>   aujourd’hui : positionnée au sein d’un spectre chromatique, dégageant une
>   gamme de nuances, étalonnée sur un nuancier.*

En résumé, au Moyen-Âge seuls les couleurs pures sont valorisées, et l'orange est un mélange de rouge et de jaune, deux couleurs chargées négativement sur le plan culturel à l'époque. Par contre, il est proche de l'or, ce qui est positif. Il faut noter aussi que cette couleur était alors difficile à produire sur le plan technique. Donc il n'y avait vraisemblablement pas de mot en usage courant pour la couleur *orange* avant la fin du Moyen-Âge.

Comment: I very much like the range of Latin terms suggested, because they give an idea of naming colours in that genre but not limited to what we think of as "orange" — suggesting that they didn't use one for that shade specifically. I bet a good source of medieval terminology would be formal descriptions of coats of arms...

Comment: I clearly didn't read your "héraldique" paragraph before writing that last sentence. Convergent thought again. Okay, on the presumption that this means that they didn't name the exact shade, j'accepterai après avoir donné un peu de temps au cas où on trouve des exemples en ancien français même des mots employés pour décrire cette couleur (ou à peu près).

Comment: @LukeSawczak - looks I have found the "ultimate reference" for the medieval history of the color _orange_. :-) Fascinating! Excellent question!

Comment: I'm wondering - since questions about culture and society are usually (with irrational exceptions), deemed unsuitable here, will this one be closed? You can't separate language and culture, what a shocker! ;-)

Comment: @Frank: Questions about culture and society are fine as far as they are related to the French language.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - see [this](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/665/la-question-sur-le-fran%C3%A7ais-en-belgique)

Comment: I consider this a linguistic issue anyway because conceptual schemes have been treated as linguistic issues in the framework I cited in my question. :) Thanks for updating the answer; that second document in particular is fascinating. Funny enough, today I was thinking that we view colours today more abstractly, separately than they did in the Middle Ages (heck, as RGB values!). But as so many instincts about the Middle Ages, that notion turns out to be quite wrong since, as that document suggests, it was actually through abstraction of colours that orange was devalued for not being "pure"!